# Centrar verticalmente un span dentro de un div

Tags: html, css, foundation

Tengo el siguiente código con Vue y Foundation, pero quiero ayuda para centrar un span verticalmente en todo el div:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    
  },
  methods: {

  }
})
```

```css
.badge {
  padding: 0.2rem 0.3rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}
.badge-cancelled {
  background: #474747;
}
.card {
  background-color: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 225px;
}
.row-start-at {
  margin-bottom: 0.6rem;
}
.card-section {
  padding: 0.4em !important;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/css/foundation.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-section">
      <span class="badge badge-cancelled">Cancelled</span>
       <div class="row row-start-at">
        <div class="columns small-16">
          <h5 class="schedule-start-at">4:40 AM</h5>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="columns small-24">
          <h4>Titulo</h4>
         </div>
        </div>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="columns small-24">
            <span class="schedule-mins">45 min</span>
          </div>
        </div><br/>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="columns small-24">
            +Add URL
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dentro del div tengo información de horas y texto, lo que quiero hacer es que la etiqueta 'Cancelled' pase al centro de todo el contenedor, y que lo de atras se vea con opacidad como la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comparto JSFiddle para que me puedan ayudar por favor: https://jsfiddle.net/bardalesj/sLfpc0ax/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que sacar `.badge` y pasarlo mas abajo, y que `.card-section` ocupe el 100% del height y le aplicas un `filter` con css, juegas con `position: absolute` y obtendrías algo como esto.

```css
.card {
  background-color: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 225px;
  position: relative;
}

.card-section {
  padding: 0.4em !important;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(2px);
}
.row-start-at {
  margin-bottom: 0.6rem;
}
.badge {
  padding: 0.2rem 0.3rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; top: 50%;
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
.badge-cancelled {
  background: #474747;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-section">
            <div class="row row-start-at">
                <div class="columns small-16">
                    <h5 class="schedule-start-at">4:40 AM</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns small-24">
                        <h6>Titulo</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns small-24">
                        <span>45 min</span>
                    </div>
                </div><br/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns small-24">
                        +Add URL
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="badge badge-cancelled">Cancelled</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como recomendación, trata siempre de seguir un orden correlativo en el css, respetando la cascada.